# Merge tag [javaslang] into [vavr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [javaslang tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javaslang/info) and the [vavr tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vavr/info) refer to the same project. It was [renamed in April 2017](http://blog.vavr.io/javaslang-changes-name-to-vavr/) due to issues with the Java™ trademark.

Comment: I think it should be a synonym, not retagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. [vavr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vavr) is now the master tag, with [javaslang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javaslang) persisting as a synonym. This should handle people who still try to use the old name.

I also manually merged the two tag wikis, because it looked like there was a bit of description in the old [javaslang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javaslang) wiki that might be worth keeping. I don't know if it's still accurate, though. Someone who actually understands what this library does might ought to take a look. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I cleaned the text up a bit and added some links; several of the contributors are SO users, so with luck one of them will come along at some point and review it.